# set the form input fileds two columns wise?

Tags: html, css, forms

i have this form which i am using for the project based learning and still i can't make the form input two column. what i have done here is set up a main div called container and two div inside the main div called left and right. use the `float` property to align the div's left and right and left div is used to show the background image and right div is used to hold the form. what i want to do is make the form two column like first name and last name stay on the first two column and email and telephone after it and password and confirm password stay after that. i have used `flex` property but still no clue how doing the work?. any idea for setting the form two column?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="bg">
                <img src="odin-lined.png" alt="">
                <h1>ODIN</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <p>This is not a real online service! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Necessitatibus, commodi!

                Sign up now to get started.</p>




            <form action="">
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="first name">FIRST NAME</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="last name">LAST NAME</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
                    <input type="email">
                </div>

                <div class="input">
                    <label for="telephone">TELEPHONE</label>
                    <input type="tel">
                </div>

                <div class="input">
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="password">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

here is the CSS

.

```
left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
 
}


.bg{
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 500px;
}


.bg img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code, i suggest you to learn how display flex works it's not hard but it will help you a lot. I changed path to css in head tag, change that and everything will work fine. Also you can see how i fixed it. :D

In your situation i would use tag placeholder="Example", it looks better and labels can make you little problems.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="bg">
                <img src="odin-lined.png" alt="">
                <h1>ODIN</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <p>This is not a real online service! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Necessitatibus, commodi!

                Sign up now to get started.</p>




            <form action="">
              <div class="col">
                <label for="first name">FIRST NAME</label>
                <input type="text">

                <label for="last name">LAST NAME</label>
                    <input type="text">
              </div>


              <div class="col">
                <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
                    <input type="email">

                    <label for="telephone">TELEPHONE</label>
                    <input type="tel">
              </div>

              <div class="col">
                <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password">

                    <label for="password">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password">
              </div>
                

                
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>




.left{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.right{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;

}


.bg{
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 500px;
}


.bg img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.col{
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.col label{
  width: 180px;
}
```